# UIWebView - Trouble displaying current URL in text field

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, nsurlrequest

I'm having problems getting the current URL through a URL request and passing it on to the text field above my web view. I tried logging it and it returns NULL, and the text field remains blank.

This is the delegate I added to my implementation file:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSURL* url = [webView.request URL];
    _webAddress.text = [url absoluteString];
}
```

And here is my WebViewController.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface WebViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIWebView *_webView;
    IBOutlet UITextField *_webAddress;
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
    NSTimer *timer;
    NSString *_webURL;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *webAddress;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *webURL;

- (IBAction) doneButton:(id)sender;


@end
```

And here is my WebViewController.m file:

```
#import "WebViewController.h"


@implementation WebViewController

@synthesize webView = _webView;
@synthesize webAddress = _webAddress;
@synthesize webURL = _webURL;


// Dismiss WebViewController
- (IBAction) doneButton:(id)sender {

    [[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];        
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSURL* url = [webView.request URL];
    _webAddress.text = [url absoluteString];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [_webView addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_webURL]]];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(loading) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)loading {
    if (!_webView.loading) 
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

        else
            [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    _webURL = nil;
    _webView = nil;
    _webAddress = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    [_webURL release];
    [_webView release];
    [_webAddress release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: I found out where I went wrong. I had to add the <UIWebViewDelegate> to my .h file, and I forgot to connect my Web View to the delegate in my File's Owner. It's working now but the initial URL that the Web View opens with does not show, just blank, but any links clicked after that show in the text field. So to correct it I had to change to "ViewDidFinishLoad" instead of "ViewDidStartLoad" in order to also get the initial URL that the Web View launches with.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` delegate instead.  This will give you the actual request.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006951-CH3-SW6

Comment: I found out where I went wrong. I had to add the <UIWebViewDelegate> to my .h file, and I forgot to connect my Web View to the delegate in my File's Owner.

It's working now but the initial URL that the Web View opens with does not show, just blank, but any links clicked after that show in the text field.

So to correct it I had to change to [CODE]ViewDidFinishLoad[/CODE] instead of [CODE]ViewDidStartLoad[/CODE] in order to also get the initial URL that the Web View launches with.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{

NSURL* url = [request  URL];
 _webAddress.text = [url absoluteString];


}
```